# Selenium Date comparison example

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jbehave

I am trying to validate dates using Selenium. So my scenario is;

```
Scenario: Date validation
When I set field <field> to value <value>
And I save the form
Then I should see error message <message>

Examples:
| field | value | message |
| startDate | 01/01/2014 | End date should be greater than start date |
| endDate | 01/01/2014 | End date should be greater than start date |
```

My step method to populate field is generic as below;

```
@When("I set field <field> to value <value>")
public void populateField(@Named("field") String fieldName, @Named("value") String value) {
    populateFieldValue(fieldName, value);
}
```

My question is since the step method is generic, how do I set the start date, then end date and display the error message in a single example line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a StringListConverter to pass lists of values to parameters

Simple example:

```
Scenario: Date validation
When I set field <field> to value <value>
Then I should see error message <message>

Examples:
| field | value | message |
| startDate | 01/01/2014 | End date should be greater than start date |
| endDate | 01/01/2014 | End date should be greater than start date |
| startDate,endDate | 01/01/2014, 01/01/2014 | display the error message in a single example line. |
```

And a test code:

```
@When("I set field <field> to value <value>")
public void xxxx(@Named("field") List<String> fields, 
                 @Named("value") List<String> values){

    System.out.println(">>>>>------------->>>>----------->>>>>");
    for( int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++ ){
        String field = fields.get(i);
        String value = values.get(i);
        System.out.println(" --> Set field: " + field + " to value: " + value);
    }

}
@Then("I should see error message <message>")
public void when(@Named("message") String message){
    System.out.println(" -------> message = " + message);
}
```

The above test generates this results:

```
Running story main/resources/test.story
>>>>>------------->>>>----------->>>>>
 --> Set field: startDate to value: 01/01/2014
 -------> message = End date should be greater than start date
>>>>>------------->>>>----------->>>>>
 --> Set field: endDate to value: 01/01/2014
 -------> message = End date should be greater than start date
>>>>>------------->>>>----------->>>>>
 --> Set field: startDate to value: 01/01/2014
 --> Set field: endDate to value: 01/01/2014
 -------> message = display the error message in a single example line.
```